# How to POST with cookies by NSURLSession

Tags: swift, cookies, ios9, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I want to POST with cookies to pass the log in system of my school, and I have done that by Python. However, I don't know how to do that with NSURLSession. I have tried to turn the cookies into a string and use the NSURLRequest.setValue, but it didn't work to me. Or I have also tried

```
let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(fields, forURL: response!.URL!)
let headers = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookies)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
```

But it didn't work either. I have searched online try to figure it out, but the answers are too old to solve the problem here. So please somebody can help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're customizing the NSURLSession instance via NSURLSessionConfiguration, you should just be able to set the cookie via the shared [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSHTTPCookieStorage/sharedHTTPCookieStorage) using the setCookie selector.

Comment: Then how? I believe I used the NSHTTPCookieStorage.setCookie(cookie, url, nil). But still nothing happened